# What type of person do i need to manage my life

Tags: billing, fund-manager

I'm looking for a person or group that can handle my financials. (for a fee or not (Fee to me means maybe 1-200 a month.)) I want to be able to give them access to the bank account and over see the bills. Paying them off and leaving me behind what i can spend. i know someone like this exists but i just cant get my hands on the name.

Comment: Why do you want somebody else to do your work ? Are you that lazy ? From your question it seems you aren't swimming around in money either. Your option is more for people who have loads of money in their accounts. Taking advice on investing your money is an option, rather then putting somebody else in control of your finances.

Comment: Find a mirror, that is the person you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use automatic bill payments to cover your credit card payments for free. This way you will not have to pay anyone.

I guess you may want someone to tell you whats going on?

Comment: I suggest you spend some time to learn these basic skills.  As I mentioned, automatic payments are probably the best way. You may also want to consider something like mint.com (Warning: This is cloud based and security is to be considered) where you add your credit cards and bank accounts and mint.com will remind you for everything you need (ex. Bill reminders, fees, budgets, etc.). I personally use this but being in IT, I understand that you are keeping your data with a 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of a Personal Assistant, or perhaps a Life Coach. As LEEMAN said, it's probably overkill, but that might be the word you're looking for.